# How I can use Runtime.getRuntime.exec with ffmpeg library in Android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm trying to establish the correct rotation in my recorded video because in some devices the setOrientationHint method doesn' work becuase in some video players may choose to ignore the compostion matrix in a video during playback, [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOrientationHint%28int%29).

So, I've decided to use the ffmpeg library. I'm develop a test for the app. In Ubuntu, I download this library and execute the configure and make to obtain the ffmpeg executable, I copy this executable to the DCIM folder in the sdcard, the same for a video what I've recorded for my camera recorder app. So, in the DCIM folder, I have the ffmpeg executable and a video.

I created a test project and in the onCreate method, I've include:

```
try {

Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard/beni/ffmpeg");
p.waitFor();

p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/mnt/sdcard/beni/ffmpeg -i /mnt/sdcard/beni/f.mp4 -vf \"transpose=1\" -r 24 -sameq /mnt/sdcard/beni/f2.mp4");
p.waitFor();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
String line = null;  
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
    System.out.println(line);  
}  




} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but I have the following warning:

```
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/mnt/sdcard/beni/ffmpeg, -i, /mnt/sdcard/beni/f.mp4, -vf, "transpose=1", -r, 24, -sameq, /mnt/sdcard/beni/f2.mp4] Working Directory: null Environment: null
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:224)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:189)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:275)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:210)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at com.example.prueba.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:222)
09-13 13:14:03.547: W/System.err(7782):     ... 17 more
```

Is this code right? Or I've done something wrong.